# 301 Redirect to Remove a URL Parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect the following URL to remove the trailing "/?fbtab=true", using .htaccess and Apache?

https://www.tudosaudavel.com/produto/kawa-kawa-piper-methysticum-forster-100g/?fbtab=true

to

https://www.tudosaudavel.com/produto/kawa-kawa-piper-methysticum-forster-100g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the query string has `fbtab=true`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fbtab=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Then I found out that what I really needed was a robots.txt, because the facebook tag was used inside facebook app :P